# .htaccess with bbPress for non logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, bbpress

I have a WordPress site with bbPress forum plugin. I created a custom page for the forum "home page". bbPress has clickable breadcrumbs and "Forum" will load the default bbPress forum home, as such I added the following to my .htaccess to redirect the user to my custom page:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /forums$ /the-forum`
This redirects the user:
from: https://okclarity.com/forums/ (bbPress forum home) 
to: https://okclarity.com/the-forum/ (custom forum home)

That works - but only for logged in users. When a user is not logged in the redirect does not work.

1. Can someone advise why this would not work for not logged in users?
2. Is there perhaps a better way to redirect the users to the custom page?

Comment: The above was posted when the site was in development. After moving to the live site, the `RewriteRule` does not work at all, even for logged in users. I have removed Forums from the breadcrumbs as a band aid solution. If anyone has a real solution please post.

Answer (score 0):

bbPress has an option for this.

1. Open WordPress Admin -> Settings -> bbPress.
2. Scroll down to **Forum Root Slug**.
3. Change **Forum Root** from **forums** to **the-forum**.
4. Open Settings -> Permalinks to clear the rewrite rules.

Make sure to remove rewrite rules you have added.

Comment: We have tried this but when doing so the bbPress page replaces our custom page at that URL.

Comment: You can't have bbPress home and custom page using the same URL. I don't understand what you want to do here, but my answer is the proper way for changing bbPress forum root slug. If you have a problem with it, most likely you try to do something that is in conflict with that. This works with any website I tried.

Comment: I am not looking to change the slug or use the same URL for two things - I am looking to redirect users from navigating to the to the bbPress forum home to my custom page.

Comment: That will not work this way, because you will have conflicting rewrite rules, and only one will be resolved (bbPress home in this case). Better to have a custom page with different URL, and write some small code that will redirect from bbPress home to that custom page.